# unable to modify appended item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append an `li` item and then modify it from an array.
If the ul has less than seven characters I want to add a new item to the ul and then be able to change the added item according to the array.
I'm able to add a new item and add the active class to it, but I can't change anything in the added li.

This is the code for append the new item:

```
if ($('ul li').length < 7 && $('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.content ul').append(newElement);
        newElement.addClass('active').focus();
}
```

And this is the code to change letters from the array (which works on the other items):

```
if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
       letterIndex = letterIndex - 1; // if li has class active jump to prev letter in array
        $(this).html(letters[letterIndex]);
}
```

Sorry if my code looks messy, I've tried a bunch of things and haven't cleaned it yet.

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq4rdfxt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4rdfxt/2/).

Keyup now looks like this:

```
case key.up:
   letterIndex = letterIndex + 1; // if li has class active jump to next letter in array
   $(this).text(letters[letterIndex]);
   $('.content').addClass('backBG'); // else add class backBG to .content and remove focus from li
   $('li').blur(); // remove focus
   break;
```

I think your if/else loops were unnecessary, so I removed them.  If you want to put them back in, you'll need to add logic to add the "active" class to whichever item has focus.

Comment: Actually, they're necessary for other things on the site that's not visible in the fiddle. But now it's only possible to change one letter, maybe you missunderstood what I wanted to achieve? Thank you anyway for the answer.